# Thinner graph of discreet X-axis in GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, expand, geom-col

I would like for my ggplot2 graph to be thinner. I only have 3 discreet points on the X axis of a barplot with geom_col and it is too thick. this is the code:

```
Lmid <- ggplot(data_est_ci_mid, aes(x=origin, y=Estimate, fill=origin), width = 0.1) + 
  geom_col(width = 1, show.legend = FALSE, linetype = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=CImin, ymax=CImax), width=.1) +
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("M","H","R"),
                   expand = c(0,0))
```

I have messed around with the expand function, but it only makes my bars thinner, not the whole graph.

Here is my graph:

Too thick graph

[image]

And my data:

```
   origin Estimate CImin CImax
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 M          70    38.6  101.
2 H          80.2  47.3  113.
3 R          83.0  54.1  112.
```

Would love the help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data

Comment: My bad, forgot to include...

Comment: I tried somethink, see if it is alright

Comment: Sorry, I already did something similar, but what i want now is that those thinner bars are pressed together and make the whole graph smaller.

Comment: I see, updated with a coordinate function that helps a little, but I guess is not the ideal

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the width inside `geom_col()` and the `expand` argument in scale.

### Data

```
df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=origin, y=Estimate, fill=origin)) + 
   geom_col(width = .25, show.legend = FALSE, linetype = 1) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=CImin, ymax=CImax), width=.1) +
   scale_x_discrete(
      limit = c("M","H","R"),
      expand = c(0.1,0)
      )+
   coord_equal(ratio = .02)
```

### Plot code

```
df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=origin, y=Estimate, fill=origin)) + 
   geom_col(width = .25, show.legend = FALSE, linetype = 1) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=CImin, ymax=CImax), width=.1) +
   scale_x_discrete(
      limit = c("M","H","R"),
      expand = c(0.1,0)
      )
```

### Output

[image]